# Stream API in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Pls, explain me, how to apply Stream API in my libgdx project?

That how I tried to apply this:

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.4.1'
    compile 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta3'
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8


   }
}
```

That what i get :

```
Error:(62, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileOptions()'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put the `compileOptions` block in this particular block. `compileOptions` is defined by the android plugin, and you must put it inside the `android` block. In a LibGDX project, you'll find the `android` block in the build.gradle file that's in the `android` module.